# Docker Build Error for dotnetcore api: Skipping project "/MyDotnetCoreLib/MyDotnetCoreLib.csproj" because it was not found

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, dotnet-core-pack

Background on my issue. I am trying to build a docker image for a dotnet core api that has a library attached to the solution referenced inside the api.When i run the docker build command I get the warning below and then build errors because it cannot reference the library.

> Skipping project "/MyDotnetCoreLib/MyDotnetCoreLib.csproj" because it was not found.

My Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyAPI.dll"]
```

My file structure is as below:

[image: screenshot of the file structure]

--Edit 
[image: screenshot of the file structure]

Error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.426MB
Step 1/10 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1 AS build-env
 ---> bf77a711b92c
Step 2/10 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ae6b78cbf588
Step 3/10 : COPY src/Accounts.NT/Accounts.NT.csproj ./
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder190366239/src/Accounts.NT/Accounts.NT.csproj: no such file or directory
PS C:\Git\Personal\Accounts.NT\src\Accounts.NT> docker build -t vumanimdabe/accounts-nt:v1.0 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.426MB
Step 1/10 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1 AS build-env
 ---> bf77a711b92c
Step 2/10 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ae6b78cbf588
Step 3/10 : COPY Accounts.NT.csproj ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b360913be4a4
Step 4/10 : RUN dotnet restore
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e9bf7172e851
Step 5/10 : COPY . ./
 ---> d4f088d6d737
Step 6/10 : RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
 ---> Running in fb8fad58131c
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.2.32702+c4012a063 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Skipping project "/Accounts.Data/Accounts.Data.csproj" because it was not found.
  Skipping project "/Accounts.Data/Accounts.Data.csproj" because it was not found.
  Restore completed in 879.4 ms for /app/Accounts.NT.csproj.
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.802/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1875,5): warning : The referenced project '../Accounts.Data/Accounts.Data.csproj' does not exist. [/app/Accounts.NT.csproj]
Controllers/AccountsController.cs(7,16): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'Accounts' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/app/Accounts.NT.csproj]
Startup.cs(6,16): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'Accounts' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/app/Accounts.NT.csproj]
Startup.cs(7,16): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'Accounts' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/app/Accounts.NT.csproj]
Controllers/AccountsController.cs(38,57): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AccountCreate' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/Accounts.NT.csproj]
Controllers/AccountsController.cs(19,26): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IAccountRepository' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/Accounts.NT.csproj]
Controllers/AccountsController.cs(21,35): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IAccountRepository' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/Accounts.NT.csproj]
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet publish -c Release -o out' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you are copying from the root of the directory, where your file is inside `Src -> MyAPI -> MyAPI.csproj`

So update your Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY src/MyAPI/*.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY src/MyAPI/ ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyAPI.dll"]
```

Comment: Just tried it. Getting another error on this statement:COPY src/MyAPI/*.csproj ./
. COPY failed: no source files were specified

Comment: is it `src` or `Src`? double check the host file

Comment: its `src`. What do you mean by checking the hostfile ?

Comment: I mean double check the file name uder src/MyAPI and where is you dockerfile?

Comment: It's under src/MyAPI

Comment: Back at the original error.`Skipping project "MyLibrary/MyLibrary.csproj" because it was not found.`

Comment: can you pls paste the screenshot of your working directory and in which director you run `docker build` commabnd?

Comment: I've just included it on the post body above.

Comment: Thanks, run the command from the above directory and check the docker ignore is there any file that mark ignore .` docker build -t myimage .`

Comment: also try with `COPY src/MyAPI/Accounts.NT.csproj ./` seems like double `dot` create issue

Comment: This is what the dockerignorefile above looks like `.dockerignore
.env
.git
.gitignore
.vs
.vscode
*/bin
*/obj
**/.toolstarget`

Comment: dockerignore seems fine, pls try with with `COPY src/MyAPI/Accounts.NT.csproj ./`

Comment: When running the cmd `docker build -t myimage .` on the directory above i get the same error.

Comment: my fault, sorry update copy command to `copy Accounts.NT.csproj ./`

Comment: still no luck. same error. I've copied the response from the ps output window to the the description above below the screenshots

Comment: omg now the error publish line `Step 6/10 : RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
 ---> Running in fb8fad58131c
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.2.32702+c4012a063 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Accounts.Data.csproj' does not exist. [/app/Accounts.NT.csproj]`

Comment: try to build now by adding `docker build --no-cache -t yourimage .`

Comment: nah it just hangs at step 4 above

Comment: Having the same issue. It says "because it was not found" on many of my csproj files. Other errors are "The type or namespace name could not be found" obviously as it can't compile the first projects.

Comment: @vumanimdabe Were you able to resolve the issue?. I am facing something similar.